# How can 2 blogs share the same users

Tags: users, migration

I have a running normal WP blog (blog 1). I want to create a Q&A section for my users, so I setup another blog with WP-Answer theme (blog 2).

The problem is I don't want my users at blog 1 have to register at blog 2 to post questions. I want they automatically grant the same privileges at blog 2.

How can this be achieved? Do you have any advice for me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'd give you an answer if I could have a look at the WP-Answers theme. Do you have a download link?

Comment: @kaiser: it's a commercial plugin and that wouldn't be nice if I put a download link here. But I can give you via email. Just let me know your email :)

Comment: The answer below looks pretty good as single sign on solution. I guess you don't need my help anymore. :)

Comment: i wanted to ask the same question, ended here instead of creating duplicate question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to install your second site on the same database but with a different table prefix, e.g. `$table_prefix = "qa_";` in `wp-config.php`

You are then able to define a custom user and/or user_meta table by adding the following lines to `wp-config.php`

```
define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', [orig_table_prefix].'my_users');
define('CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', [orig_table_prefix].'my_usermeta');
```

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Custom_User_and_Usermeta_Tables

I have read somewhere before that you may have to sort out a couple of issues of admin users on the second site, can't find the link at the moment.

Comment: +1. Actually, I use 2 databases now. But your solution looks good. The site is in developing, so I'll install the WP-Answers on the same db. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest would be to keep one site, and only apply your Q&A styles to the pages you need. That way you keep everything centralized in one WP install.

If you use [body_class()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) you can target any page/post from your CSS and apply the styles you want only where you need them.

It would go something like this, if your Q&A pages have a common template named `question_answer.php` you can style them like with :

```
.page-template-question_answer{ background:#FAFAFA }
.page-template-question_answer #conent{ width:500px }
```

Comment: I agree. I see absolutely no reason to separate blog functionality into an entirely separate WordPress install.

Comment: The problem is I don't want to reinvent the wheel. WP-Answers theme is good, and I just want to use it. I think using a page template for Q&A section is hard to extendable in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you'll probably want them to be automatically logged in to the Q&A site, otherwise it's not much better than registering twice. Your best bet is probably to change your original site to a multisite instance and have the Q&A site be another site within the same WordPress installation. Then find a plugin that will automatically grant a certain user role without you having to add them manually, such as http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-user-management/

Also see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

If you're on shared hosting, it's possible that you might run into difficulties getting multisite set up, but it's still probably the best solution.

Comment: +1. I was thinking about MultiSite, but I don't have much experience about this. I need to test this carefully. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that you'll need *not only* the `CUSTOM_USER_(META_)TABLE` pointing to the main sites user table in the wp-config.php of your child site, but *also* the `AUTH_KEY, SECURE_AUTH_KEY, LOGGED_IN_KEY, NONCE_KEY` constants should be exactly the same as on your main site. This will avoid generating new passwords. Should work out of the box.